# Laravel update data that is an array works while insert does not

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Using Laravel 9, Im able to UPDATE an empty field hole_data by posting an array of objects:

JS:

```
data = {
   id:1,
   name:'A Name',
   hole_data: [{…}, {…}]
}

await axiosClient.post('/updateholedata', data);
```

Laravel/PHP

```
public function updateHoleData(Request $request) {
   DB::table('holes')
   ->where('id', $request->id)
   ->update(['hole_data' => $request->hole_data]);              
   return $this->index();
}
```

But when i do an INSERT (data same as above without ID)  I get an "Array to string conversion" error on hole_data:

JS:

```
await axiosClient.post('/addholedata', data);
```

Laravel/PHP:

```
public function addHoleData(Request $request) {
   $id = DB::table('holes')->insertGetId (['hole_data' => $request->hole_data]);
   return $id;
}
```

And the unusual thing that's making my head scratch is that i can INSERT the name then get the ID and then UPDATE the hole_data using the ID.

```
public function addHoleData(Request $request) {
   $id = DB::table('holes')->insertGetId (['name' => $request->name]); //Insert to get ID

   DB::table('holes')
   ->where('id', $id) //use id to insert hole_data
   ->update(['hole_data' => $request->hole_data])
}
```

Why am i getting an error on just inserting when i can insert then update on the same data from the request?

Comment: Use Eloquent with built-in casting from array to JSON. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: Also you can't POST complex data structures to the server. They are getting transformed into something else by the client, likely problem is the transform back is failing on the server side in one case but not the other. Inspect the values your client sends, check routing of data, use debug logging, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Insert try to **json_encode()** the hole_data if it is not a string

As MySQL will not allows complicated data structures (like array of objects) you can json_encode and store it as a string

```
['hole_data' => json_encode($request->hole_data)]
```

Comment: Yes I can insert using json_encode, but i find it strange that MySQL doesn't accept $request->hole_data on insert but does on update.

Comment: @deach I feels strange too, Check on the source you will get some idea. And if you get any idea, Kindly share with me

Answer (score 0):

This is comment but i have bigger text.

In your JS `hole_data` accept an array

```
   hole_data: [{…}, {…}]
```

On PHP inserting what is inside `$request->hole_data`

```
   $id = DB::table('holes')->insertGetId (['hole_data' => $request->hole_data]);
```

What you get when you `dd($request->hole_data)` before query, is it string or array?

Database table is `holes`, do you have `Model` **Hole** or **Holes**
If you have Model, did you use `$cast` for `hole_data` field and what is the `cast` value